# Problemas com classe PDO não encontrada

Tags: php, pdo, design-pattern

Estou estudando um livro no qual tenho que efetuar algumas queryes através de um design pattern TableDataGateway porem estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'classes\tgd\PDO' not found in C:\xampp
>   \htdocs\livro_php_poo_12_persistencia\classes\tgd\Connect.php:12
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 C:\xampp\htdocs\livro_php_poo_12_persistencia
>   \exemplo_table_data_gateway2.php(24): classes\tgd\Connect->__construct()
>
> 1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\livro_php_poo_12_persistencia\classes
>   \tgd\Connect.php on line 12

***index***

***produto***

```
    <?php
namespace classes\tgd;
class Produto {
    private static $conn;
    private $data;

    public static function setConnection(PDO $conn){

        self::$conn = $conn; 
        ProdutoGateway::setConnection(self::$conn);

    }
    function __get($prop) {
        return $this->data[$prop];
    }
//...
}
```

***TableDataGateway***

```
namespace classes\tgd;

class ProdutoGateway {

    private static $conn;

    public function setConnection(PDO $conn){
        self::$conn = $conn;
    }
    //fazendo buscar por id
    public function find($id,$class = 'stdClass'){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM produto WHERE id=:id";
        print "$sql<br>\n";
        $result = self::$conn->prepare($sql);
        $result->bindValue(":id",$id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $result->execute();
        return $result->fetchObject($class);
    }

    //...
}
```

***conexão***

```
<?php
namespace classes\tgd;


class Connect {
    private static $conn;
    const CONN = array('HOST'=>'xxx','USER'=>'xxx','PASS'=>xxx,'DATA'=>'xxx');

    public function __construct(){
        self::$conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=".self::CONN['HOST'].";"
        . "dbname=".self::CONN['DATA'],self::CONN['USER'],self::CONN['PASS']);
        $conn = self::$conn;
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        return Produto::setConnection($conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Você está utilizando uma classe global dentro de um *namespace*, então precisa de uma barra invertida. Nos métodos que recebem o PDO como parâmetro, coloque `\PDO` ao invés de `PDO`.

Comment: eu ja fiz isso amigo nao deu certo

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro citada, acredito fielmente que esse era o erro. Tem como atualizar a pergunta com o novo código? Aliás, a mensagem de erro permaneceu a mesma?

Comment: Atualizar a pergunta implica em editá-la. Se mudou o erro, coloque o código e a mensagem de erro na pergunta.

Comment: pronto atualizado

Comment: Adriano, o problema estava no parâmetro dos métodos, não na instância. Para simplificar, retire essa barra invertida que colocou e coloque `use PDO` em **todos** os arquivos que fazendo referência à classe, incluindo *TableDataGateway* e *produto*.

Comment: funcionou obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

Quando você referencia uma classe dentro de um *namespace* sem identificá-la com a instrução `use`, o PHP entenderá que esta classe também pertencerá ao *namespace*. Isto é, ao fazer:

```
<?php

namespace classes\tgd;

class Foo {
    public function method(PDO $pdo) {}
}
```

O PHP entenderá que a classe `PDO` pertence ao *namespace* `classes\tgd`. Para resolver isso, sempre que você utilizar a classe dentro de um *namespace*, você precisa identificar sua origem. Como a PDO pertence ao contexto global, basta colocar:

```
use PDO;
```

Ficando algo semelhante a:

```
<?php

namespace classes\tgd;

use PDO;

class Foo {
    public function method(PDO $pdo) {}
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, é que eu acabei de entrar neste mundo de `namespaces e design patterns`